# two image swaps constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```css
.question1sidebar{
 top: 150px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question2sidebar{
 top: 220px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question3sidebar{
 top: 290px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question4sidebar{
 top: 360px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question5sidebar{
 top: 430px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question6sidebar{
 top: 500px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.question7sidebar{
 top: 570px;
 left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-color: #5D5C5A;
}
.left{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: white;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 300px 100px;
 border-right: solid #918A88;
 border-bottom: solid #7C7776;
}
```

So i am making a website that contains 7 stages and on the side i put something like stage 1-7 and what i basically want is what ever level the user is on there will be a grey check mark switching to green check mark back and fourth indicating that they are on that level and when they proceed onto the next level with a click a button the next level with be flashing(going from grey check mark to green mark back to grey check mark)

```js
function question1(){
 if(var i=0; i>2; i++){
  var greycheckmark = document.getElementById("greycheckmark");
  this.src = "img/green.png"
   i++
 }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
 <div class="question1sidebar">
  Question1
</div>
<img src="img/grey.png" id="greycheckmark" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 75px; position: absolute; top: 143px; left: 230px;" onload="question1()">
 <div class="question2sidebar">
  Question2
</div>
 <div class="question3sidebar">
  Question3
</div>
 <div class="question4sidebar">
  Question4
</div>
 <div class="question5sidebar">
  Question5
</div>
 <div class="question6sidebar">
  Question6
</div>
 <div class="question7sidebar">
  Question7
</div>
</div>
```

What i was trying to accomplish with javascript is to do a if and else statement with incrementer so like if i is equal to 0 then it will increment once and display a different picture then decrease and display the original image

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval` function in JS to toggle the gray and green images.

Here is a sample JavaScript that I wrote:

```
//We use this to check if the image is grey or green
var active = false;

  setInterval(function(){
    var greycheckmark = document.getElementById("greycheckmark");

    //If it is active(green) set it to grey
    if(active)
    {
        //You will need to replace this image with your grey image
        greycheckmark.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/d/J/p/D/g/check-grey-hi.png";
    }
    else
    {
         //You will need to replace this image with your green image
         greycheckmark.src = "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/167549/Kliponious-green-tick.png"
    }

    //change the state to the opposite (active -> inactive or vice versa)
    active = !active

  //This specifies the timeout of the function in milliseconds(The bigger the value the slower the change)
  }, 500);
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kjusoaj/